# How do I delete a save in a slot in Final Fantasy 1 for GBA?

Tags: emulation, final-fantasy

I accidentally saved to the 3rd slot by mis-clicking (I use an emulator). Now I have two copies of the save. How do I delete the save I have on the 3rd slot? If it's not possible natively in-game, are there hacks I can do on the save file to remove it?

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you talking about the in-game saves or the emulators save slots?

Comment: In-game save. I can delete emulator saves manually any time I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can natively 'delete' the game save without erasing your current save slot as well.

As for a hack, I've never come across one for people to delete particular game saves (for any game). I daresay the emulator save file is a direct (S)RAM dump, and with the right tool you might be able to trial and error/ brute force remove it, but this would take time.

Other than that, you could try and find a friend (or a website) that has a save file for the level you are on, and download and use that.

Your best bet is to overwrite the extra save with a new game. It won't be blank, but at least it won't stand out

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Having an un-used non-blank save space in a game is one of my pet peeves sadly. :/

Comment: @ShedoSurashu - Mine too, sadly. I just fix it by playing through the game again :D

Comment: I was afraid that's how I would be going. I don't want to use other people's saves mainly because those weren't my build and my characters. I just wanted confirmation that there is indeed nothing I can do to remove the extra save. Thanks again! :)